# How to Connect to Oracle Database Through Alfresco Javascript API

Tags: java, javascript, database, oracle, alfresco

So I have been working with Alfresco for a project I'm currently working on, and one of the newest requirements for the project is that I pull a sequence number from our Oracle database and populate a custom property within a space in Alfresco.

```
var conObj = new ActiveXObject('ADODB.Connection');
var connectionString = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(CID=GTU_APP)(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=IP ADDRESS)(PORT=XXXX)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=your_SID)(SERVER=DEDICATED)));User Id=username;Password=pwd;"
                                conObj.Open(connectionString);

var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
var caseID;

sql = "INSERT INTO case(mod_dt,mod_user) values(sysdate,’user’) RETURNING id"

rs.Open(sql, conObj);

caseID = rs(0);
logger.log("The new case id is: " + caseID);

rs.close;
```

However, this returned saying:

`Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "ActiveXObject" is not defined. (workspace://SpacesStore/b3145512-e54d-4d9e-9655-0b6ae678e39b#141)`

Which made me realize Alfresco's Javascript API doesn't have the full functionality of Javascript. I had read something about creating your own java class and calling them from within the Alfresco javascript, but I had not seen any good examples. Does anyone have experience with this or could they demonstrate a simple example of creating a java class to call from within Alfresco Javascript?

Comment: Could you just attach a rule to the parent folder, which either adds an aspect with the mandatory property, or runs a JS snippet that adds the property?

Comment: I think we've found a way to add a custom aspect/property to the folder. However, now we are trying to figure out how to connect to our Oracle database through the Alfresco Javascript API, so that we can pull a value to insert into our custom property field.

Comment: You'll probably want to write a java webscript that exposes the information, so you can use the oracle java API to do the query. Probably warrants a new question though

Comment: Do you know of any good examples of this being done? And the thing is, we currently have a javascript file that runs based on a rule and creates our dynamic folder structure in Alfresco. Would we be able to call a java class that uses the oracle java api from within that Alfresco javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ActiveXObject` is an IE specific thing, it's not available in non-IE browsers so it's hardly surprising that it isn't available in server-side JavaScript!

As I understand it, you're writing your JavaScript to be run as a rule, so it'll be executed in the Alfresco Repository tier. That makes life slightly easier. What you'll probably want to do is write some Java code that handles the connection and querying of Oracle, using Oracle's Java APIs (JDBC or similar).

When running in the repository, your JavaScript already has access [to a large number of "root" objects](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.alfresco.enterprise.doc%2Freferences%2FAPI-JS-rootscoped.html), which can be used to perform a variety of operations on the repository. What you'll want to do is inject your new Java class as an additional one, so it's available for your rule script to use when it runs.

(If you were writing a webscript, then you could just arrange to have the java object made available to the JavaScript model of your webscript. However, as you're doing a rule, that's not an option)

To do that, have your new class extend [BaseScopableProcessorExtension](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/repository/org/alfresco/repo/jscript/BaseScopableProcessorExtension.html). Then, when you define a spring bean for it, set the `extensionName` property to control the name it appears in JavaScript as. There are quite a few examples in Alfresco itself you can look at for this, `ScriptSiteSevice` (bean id `siteScriptService`) is one that springs to mind.

In case you're new to spring and Alfresco, I'd suggest you either wrap your whole thing up as a module (AMP), or cheat a little and just drop the context file in a new `alfresco/extensions` directory under your tomcat shared classes. Your file would look something like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC '-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN' 'http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd'>
<beans>
  <bean id="myOracleQueryBean" parent="baseJavaScriptExtension" 
        class="com.my.comany.namespace.alfresco.OracleScriptQuery">
    <!-- What it should be called in JS -->
    <property name="extensionName">
        <value>oracleQuery</value>
    </property>
    <!-- Inject any other things that your bean needs here -->
    <!-- eg some Oracle stuff from Spring -->
</bean>
```

Comment: If I understood you correctly, I should write a class that extends this "BaseScopableProcessorExtension", queries the database and returns a value. Then when you say define the spring bean, do you mean the one in the file located in `C:\Alfresco\tomcat\webapps\alfresco\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\script-services-context.xml`? If so, then my main questions are: Do I need to find a specific jar file to add to my build path to extend BaseScopableProcessorExtension, if so, where do I find it? Does it matter what I name my class, and where should I put the class? And how would I define my bean?

Comment: And when I say how would you define the bean, what I mean is like, I believe the bean would look like : `<bean id="thisSQLClassName" parent="?????" class="location of class">
        <property name="extensionName">
            <value>SqlQuery</value>
        </property>
    </bean>` However, what would the parent value be? And again, where would I need to place my class in order to reference it in the class value? I see a lot of `"org.alfresco.repo.jscript.app."` references in other class field within this file.

Comment: Put it in your own namespace, then build it as a jar and put that somewhere where tomcat can find it, much as you'll do for your context file. `BaseScopableProcessorExtension` is in the core Alfresco repository jar